# Get Values From Json Object Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdictionary

i am using objective c and here is my problem..

```
(
        {
        error = 0;
        newsletter = (
                     {
                      date = "2015-11-23";
                      description = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop p";
                      id = 42;
                      image = "mylink/uploads/14482883361619729430.png";
                      "post_count" = 2;
                      "posted_by" = admin;
                      title = Testing;
                    },
                    {
                     date = "2015-11-28";
                     description = "I am testing";
                     id = 48;
                     image = "mylink/ips/uploads/14486977841870344075.jpg";
                     "post_count" = 1;
                     "posted_by" = admin;
                     title = "Ips Informa";
                    }
                    );
       }
)
```

Above is my json string am retrieving from asihttpRequest

now i want to display the newsletter eg.date, title, description in table view

i have just got the array  with the following :

```
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData //1
                                                                   options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                                     error:&err];
```

I am getting output with the following code:

```
NSLog(@"NewLetter Title: %@", json);
```

The count of as following:

```
NSLog(@"Count is - %lu",[json count]);
```

Count is - 1

i am new to objective C,i tried to solve, but didnt find a way to get the data of newsletter?

Comment: Don't repost your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every JSON message has a single top-level object.  If you look at the JSON:

```
(
    {
```

You can see that you have a top-level `(` array `)` of `{` dictionaries `}`.  See [json.org](http://www.json.org/) for full details.

So you are already on the right track with your code.  You just need to access each dictionary within the array, however the JSON could actually be anything, so you need to code defensively and check it's an `NSArray` before accessing it:

```
NSArray* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                                                options:0
                                                  error:&err];
if ([json isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
    for (NSDictionary *dict in json) {
        NSNumber *error = dict[@"error"];
        NSArray *newsletter = dict[@"newsletter"];
        for (NSDictionary *entry in newsletter) {
            NSNumber *identity = entry[@"id"];
            NSString *description = entry[@"description"];
            // etc.
        }
    }
} else if (err) {
    NSLog(@"Error in JSON: %@", [err localizedDescription]);
} else {
    NSLog(@"Unsupported JSON received");
}
```

I don't know why you are getting count = 1 as that does not match the JSON you posted; you should log the actual JSON for debugging purposes:

```
NSLog(@"Received JSON: %@", [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[responseData bytes]]);
```

Comment: @trojanfoe: The count is one because the root array contains one item and there is no crash because both `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` respond to `count`.

Comment: @vadian Indeed; my code is no correct; there is a newsletter array within the dictionary.  I will correct it.

Comment: @user3015451 The code in my original answer should *not* have worked!  It should do now, though.

Answer (score 0):

json is now an`NSDictionary`, so use the regular accessors:

```
NSDictionary *firstObject = json[0];

NSDictionary *newsletter = firstObject[@"newsletter"];

NSString *firstDescription = newsletter[@"description"];
```

Comment: The first line of code that you deleted was nonsense. You should have fixed it instead of deleting.

Comment: No, you should act maturely and question it rather than labelling it a 'nonsense' within two minutes of me posting it. I reviewed the code I posted  and corrected it. Leave your rudeness at home please @gnasher729: this isn't the place for it

Comment: When I posted my comment, it was nonsense. And you never fixed the nonsense, you deleted it, when it was easily fixable.

Answer (score 0):

The `json` object contains an `NSArray` (represented by parentheses) with one item, that's why the count is 1.

Get the contents of the item with

```
json[0]
```

which is a `NSDictionary` (represented by braces).

Get the value for the key `newsletter` with

```
json[0][@"newsletter"]
```

This value is again an `NSArray`.

Continue retrieving items of an array by numeric subscription (like `[0]`) and dictionary items by key subscription (like `[@"date"]`)

Comment: Seems someone didn't like your answer. I can't see anything wrong with it. Actually, there isn't anything wrong with it. Actually, you are back to zero :-)

Answer (score -1):

If you are new to Objective-C then you must learn all of the following:

One. The classes NSArray and NSDictionary.

Two. The method isKindOfClass which tells you what an object is.

Three. Iterating through arrays, preferably using fast enumeration.

Four. Accessing the keys of a dictionary, using objectForKey or preferably the index notation.

When you know all these four, you may start to look at parsing JSON.

BTW. You cannot possibly get "the date of the newsletter", because there could be any number of newsletters, and the one that you have has two dates. You really need to think about what data you are receiving and what you want to do with them.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all - too vague. You might as well have told the asker to 'learn objective-c'.

Comment: Which is absolutely what he should do. Anything wrong with telling people to learn Objective-C if they want to write Objective-C code?

Comment: *sigh* yes: or else, that would be an answer on any objective-c tag...